# Angular JS | how to enforce call to ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I have a list which I iterate with `ng-repeat`.

for each `<li>` element, I use `ng-init="foo(item)"` to calculate the value for display.

this is working well.

I want to implement a refresh button, but problem is that `ng-init` is not called again.

How can i enforce the call for `ng-init` again?

i've tried to call `$scope.apply()` but that did not help.

Comment: you should provide some fragments of your code related to this issue

Comment: You should do these calculations in controller before rendering. It is not the best practice to use ng-init like this.

Answer (score 1):

If re-rendering is not an issue, you can clear the ng-repeat array then add it back. This will re-render the ng-repeat causing ng-init to fire on each item again.

The downside to this is it will "flicker" depending how you have your css/animations setup. If you want the refresh to be seamless without visible change to the render, you'll likely need to use something other than ng-init.

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't have to do anything with '$scope.apply()'. 'ng-init' will only fire once, during DOM rendering. Rather than using ng-init, did you try angular interpolation binding?
For example - `<li><span>{{foo(item)}}</span></li>`